# Wireless signal low or nonexistent, can't connect on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, network-manager

I just got my Asus K53S laptop back from a repair (DC power jack was replaced) and my wireless does not work.

Wifi signal is either extremely low or nonexistent and I can't successfully connect, even if other devices are connected with good signal.

Running `sudo lshw -C network` I get:

```
  *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 01
   serial: e0:b9:a5:27:e5:9b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-72-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:17 memory:de200000-de20ffff
   *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: enp4s0
   version: 06
   serial: bc:ae:c5:5f:62:dc
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-1.fw ip=192.168.0.163 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:25 ioport:a000(size=256) memory:d2104000-d2104fff memory:d2100000-d2103fff
```

The driver I have installed is : NVIDIA binary driver - version 375.39 from nvidia-375 (proprietary, tested)

Running `sudo iwlist scan` with two strong wifi signals in range, I often get "no scan results" but when I do get a response, here is an example:

```
wlp3s0    Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: 06:18:D6:E7:7D:F6
                Channel:1
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Quality=21/70  Signal level=-89 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"WIMToffice"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000003111f0453d
                Extra: Last beacon: 944ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000A57494D546F6666696365
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B968C129824
                IE: Unknown: 030101
                IE: Unknown: 050400010020
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 3204B048606C
                IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC011BFFFF000000000000000000000100000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D1601000D00000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 7F080000000000000040
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                IE: Unknown: DD1300156D00010100010212E581060418D6E67DF6
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
      Cell 02 - Address: 06:18:D6:E7:7D:E1
                Channel:6
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=18/70  Signal level=-92 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"WIMToffice"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=00000058a17bd180
                Extra: Last beacon: 644ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000A57494D546F6666696365
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B968C129824
                IE: Unknown: 030106
                IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 3204B048606C
                IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC011BFFFF000000000000000000000100000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D1606000D00000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 7F080000000000000040
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                IE: Unknown: DD1300156D00010100010212E581060418D6E67DE1
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

I've also tried booting Ubuntu 16.04 from a live CD, and I get exactly the same behaviour.

Does this prove that here is something wrong with the hardware? Please do suggest any more information I can share.

Comment: Standing close to your wireless router, please run the terminal command: `sudo iwlist scan` Please tell us the quality of your own network. For example, I am about 9.5 meters from my router and I get Quality=56/70. If your reading is remarkably lower, we'd suspect that the antenna wire(s) are not secured.

Comment: Running that command a few times, I'm getting "no scan results". But twice when there were results the quality was 24/70 and 18/70 respectively. This signal is high on other devices like my iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the tech guy didn't connect your WiFi antenna after working on your laptop 
look at [Disassembly Procedures](http://www.aformatique.fr/manual/asus_k53_series_notebook.pdf) (see step 3).

You just need to open it and connect the 2 wires to the card it's about 5 minutes of work (page 4 get good pictures)